# Nanobox Documentation Break After Rails 5.1 for boot.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nanoboxio

Copying the boot.rb code will break after 5.1

```
require 'rails/commands/server'
module Rails
  class Server
    alias :_default_options :default_options
    def default_options
      _default_options.merge!(Host:'0.0.0.0')
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should correct the problem

```
require 'rails/command'
require 'rails/commands/server/server_command'
module Rails
  class Server
    alias :_default_options :default_options
    def default_options
      _default_options.merge!(Host:'0.0.0.0')
    end
  end
end
```